# How would i execute another command by a link from within 1 command on my discord bot?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a help embed, but I have a fair few commands now, is there any chance I could send a help embed, then if a user clicks a link in the embed, it sends a more specific embed containing the help they want? I'm just wondering how I would do this because I'm completely stumped. Any help will be received gratefully.

Comment: Sure if you had your own web server, but that gets quite complex, instead what people tend to do, is use Discord reactions. Or just simply follow up commands.

Comment: Discord reactions? so if a user responded :x: to the embed it would trigger an event that responded with the help? sounds good to me - thank you very much